# Echo value of select box

Tags: php

So I have a basic select dropdown box:

```
      <select class="form-control" name="work_place">
        <option>Work Place 1</option>
        <option>Work Place 2</option>
        <option>Work Place 3</option>
        <option>Work Place 4</option>
      </select>
```

With php code:

```
$work  = $_POST['work_place'];
```

If I want to edit it later, what is the best way to echo selected value?

**SOLVED**
Thanks for the "help", here is the answer:

```
      <select class="form-control" name="work_place">
        <option <?php echo ($edit_row["workPlace"] === "Work Place 1")?"selected" : ""; ?> >Work Place 1</option>
        <option <?php echo ($edit_row["workPlace"] === "Work Place 2")?"selected" : ""; ?> >Work Place 2</option>
        <option <?php echo ($edit_row["workPlace"] === "Work Place 3")?"selected" : ""; ?> >Work Place 3</option>
        <option <?php echo ($edit_row["workPlace"] === "Work Place 4")?"selected" : ""; ?> >Work Place 4</option>
      </select>
```

It echoes the selected dropdown option.

Comment: Unclear. Not Much Information.

Comment: Could you please clarify what the problem is? What do you mean by "edit it later"?

Comment: @Epodax Well, it is a human resource system. I add worker, input all their info, one info is their working place. It is selected via select box. I can save that in database. Later, if needed, I want to click Edit button on the worker and alter the "work place" info. But I don't know how to echo selected value from database.

Comment: I'm still a tad unsure what the actual problem is? Are you trying to figure out how to save the data into the database or how to set the work_place to the one saved in the database? If that's the case you can use `selected` on a option.

Comment: @Epodax no. when I'm adding the worker info, I successfully add the data to the database. Confusing part is, when I want to edit the worker, I would like to display the already selected dropdown value as default, and I can then select another value or leave this to be.

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```
<form action="" method="post"> 
     <select class="form-control" name="work_place">
        <option value="Work Place 1">Work Place 1</option>
        <option value="Work Place 2">Work Place 2</option>
        <option value="Work Place 3">Work Place 3</option>
        <option value="Work Place 4">Work Place 4</option>
      </select>
      <input type="submit" value="go" />
      </form>
      <?php 
      $post = (isset($_POST['work_place'])) ? $_POST['work_place'] : '';
      echo $post;
      ?>
```

Comment: If you don't have a `value` attribute, it gets the value from the text content. Why do you think this will make any difference?

Comment: there's no difference .i just created form he can use as tutorial